# Unable to access flight-review software on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have set up an AWS EC2 instance and installed the necessary packages to run the flight-review software. However, I am unable to access the flight-review software on the EC2 instance.

I tried running the command

```
`./serve.py --show`
```

on the EC2 instance, but it doesn't give any response.When I ran

```
sudo bokeh serve serve.py --port 5006,
```

it indicated that the server is running on port 5006. However, when I try to access the URL http://localhost:5006/serve, the site cannot be reached.

Additionally, when I open the EC2 instance's public IP address, it shows a "**It Works!**" message instead of the flight-review software.

I expected that running the command ./serve.py --show on the EC2 instance would open the flight-review software in a new page, similar to how it works on my local system. I also expected that accessing the URL https://localhost:5006/serve would display the flight-review software. However, neither of these expectations were met, and I am unsure of how to resolve this issue.

when i run

```
./serve.py --show
```

and

```
 curl http://localhost:5006
```

simultaneously it prints the html content of the file.

Comment: If you login to the instance via SSH and run `curl https://localhost:5006/serve`, does it respond with anything?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Hi, after reading your response I realised that I had not connected my instance to ssh, which I did later on but for some reason it said permission denied and I had to repeat the entire process with a new instance which I logged in through ssh and I also ran the command you gave and it gave a html document of bokeh library as the result

Comment: "when I open the EC2 instance's public IP address" Do you mean you're accessing `http://52.1.2.3/` or `http://52.1.2.3:5006/` ?

Comment: Excellent! What is the configuration of the Security Group associated with the instance? Do the Inbound rules permit access to port 5006? If so, you should be able to access it via `http://1.2.3.4/serve` (using the correct public IP address).

Comment: @AnonCoward I meant http://52.1.2.3/

Comment: @JohnRotenstein The security group includes ssh port 22, http port 80 and https port 443, I am not sure how to include port 5006, like specifically what is it's type?
Also, if i include that port as well, will I be able to directly open the site or will still be needed to run the command simultaneously?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have added the port 5600 with source 0.0.0/0, but it still doesn't seem to work

Comment: Hang on, should it be `5600` or `5006`? Your question is showing `5006`. Add that to the Security Group Inbound rule, then point your browser to: `http://1.2.3.4:5006/serve` (change `1.2.3.4` to match your Public IP address). (Sorry, I forgot to include the port number in my earlier comment.)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks a lot. It definitely worked. The website is now opening with http://1.2.3.4:5006 but it's kind of distorted, may be dimension issue. Also, is there a way to open the site with just http://1.2.3.4?

Comment: Right now if i go for only http://1.2.3.4 it gives a page 
'Index of/  Name Last modified Size Description
Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at 3.110.218.111 Port 80' and after I add :5006 the website opens.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Update: Its working with just the public ip address after updating my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Since your service is running on port 5006, you will need to add an Inbound rule on the Security Group to allow inbound traffic on port 5006.

You could then access the service on:

```
http://1.2.3.4:5006/serve
```

(where `1.2.3.4` should be replaced with the actual public IP address)

It might be more convenient to run it on default HTTP port 80 by modifying the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file. You could then access the site via:

```
http://1.2.3.4/serve
```